# make a php curl with port number

Tags: php, curl, port

I'm trying to read http://free.freeshoutcast.com:39072/7.html this page, I tried this code,

```
<?php
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
    {
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        echo curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        $contents = curl_exec($c);
        echo curl_error($c);
        curl_close($c);

        if ($contents) return $contents;
            else return FALSE;
    }

echo curl_get_file_contents("http://free.freeshoutcast.com:39072/7.html");
?>
```

It's working on localhost but, not working on server (godaddy/shared hosting)

- curl is enabled
- getting "couldn't connect to host" error if I try to get a file with port number.
- curl_get_file_contents("http://www.google.com"); is working.
- tried curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PORT, "39072"); //same error.

Where am I wrong?
Thanks.

---

**EDIT: I've solved this problem by using [yql](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/), if it helps to somebody.**

Comment: Why does it have to be that port number

Comment: @Ibu It's a radio streaming host and working with port number, It's beyond my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server most likely have a firewall rule blocking outgoing access for unusual ports.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider emulating a user-agent using `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`. I have worked on projects before where we couldn't gain access without setting this value.

Answer (score 1):

Godaddy has this thing where you can not do certain things. It is more likely that the port you are trying to connect is blocked infact with godaddy you can only use what THEY offer. I have unsuccessful experience using Gmail as my SMTP, turns out that Godaddy do not allow such connections.

I will recommend if you want to utilize full power of php, OS etc then switch to Virtual private Hosting and select a good host with a cheap plan. I am happy after I left GD.

Comment: you're right, not only this, I have so much problem with godaddy, thanks for advice.